# Type coercion to string in helm templates

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an helm chart defining some environment variables, like this

```
...

  containers:
    - name: {{.Values.app }}
      image: "{{ .Values.global.registry }}/{{ .Values.deployment.repository }}:{{ .Values.deployment.tag }}"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

...       

      env:
        - name: XXX
          value: "{{ .Values.configmap.xxx }}"
        - name: YYY
          value: "{{ .Values.configmap.yyy }}"
...
```

If I define my values like this, everything works well:

```
mychart:
    configmap:
        xxx: "ABC"
        yyy: "DEF"
```

If I use values containing only numbers:

```
mychart:
    configmap:
        xxx: "123"
        yyy: "456"
```

The deployment fails with a message saying "Upgrade failed: cannot patch "xxx" with kind ConfigMap: "" is invalid: patch: Invalid value ...."

I tried a lot of combinations like use quotations of the values in the template, piping with the toString function, using !!string, etc. but I can't make it work.

Comment: Should not be `{{ .Values.mychart.configmap.yyy }}`?

Comment: @Andromeda not really, helm ".Values" is smart enough to lookup the tree of values relatively to the current object, then its parent, etc. - it works well when specifiying strings

Comment: What is the result of `helm template .`?